# Android app encoding problem - not display ÅÄÖ properly

Tags: android, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

When user enters a value 'Nedskräpning' in a EditTextbox, it is saved as 'NedskrÃ¤pning' in the database. So I am assuming this error is generated from the Android part of the application. UPDATE: <-- probably false assumption?

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/commentTextBox"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

The java code:

```
commentTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.commentTextBox);
crapport.setComment(commentTextBox.getText().toString());
```

Then this crapport is saved in the database.

Any tips on how to solve this?

UPDATE: This is my Apache CXF webservice:

```
  @Path("/crapportService/")
public class CrapportServiceImpl implements CrapportService {

    @Autowired
    private CrapportController crapportController;

    @Override
    @Path("image")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String addReport(MultipartBody multipartBody) {

        List<Attachment> attachmentList = new ArrayList<Attachment>();
        attachmentList = multipartBody.getAllAttachments();

        if (attachmentList.size() == 0){
            return "No attachments";
        }

        try {
            crapportController.processReportFromClient(attachmentList);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error: FileNotFoundException";
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return "Error: NullPointerException";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Error: IOException";
        }

        return "Success";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I looks to me your database uses ISO-8859-15 or ISO-8859-1 as encoding, the string from Android is in UTF-8 and if stored into the database the high word and the low word from the UTF-8 "Ä" get split into their two ISO-8859-1 counterparts, making it "Ã¤".

Comment: I checked the Database and it can handle UTF-8 characters, it was configured as Varchar. It was stored the way it was stored because my webservice stored in that way. (I understood this by manually inserting åäö-characters in the database, which worked). So probably the problem lies in the webservice, please check my original post to see what that looks like.

Comment: So, if you store data into your database hardcoded into your database this is stored correctly? If not, there might be a configuration issue with your jdbc driver which assumes you want to store some ISO stuff. Or if it is stored correctly your servlet container/app server might assume the wrong encoding for the web service posts (tracing the web request will help with this). Unfortuneately there is a lot of stuff involved which can break your encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by passing a character encoding argument to the string-creation. 
eg) new String("values", Charset.forName("UTF-8")) in the controller part of the backend-application.

Comment: Be careful: that's more or less just a workaround, as you force the string to be read as UTF-8, still something messes up your data and converts it into some ISO-Encoding before it gets to this call.

Comment: I see, will have to check that out then.